# Why doesn't Stack Overflow use a best answer chosen by votes?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I often see many questions where users poor their hearts out creating high-quality answers that are merely upvoted, but never selected as the answer. The user who asks the question picks the answer that may not be the correct or best one. They may also pick an answer based on criteria they never specified.

Why doesn't Stack Overflow use a best answer system based on votes?

Comment: "Why [something]" can't really be a feature request, retagged.